# Extracting date year from aggregate result query

Tags: aggregate

Below is the aggregate result query to get the minimum and maximum date values(start and end) from an object , objX.
However the ask is to extract only the year from the result. How can that be done?
I tried using certain methods such as date.year(), but without success.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [Select min(Start_Date__c),max(End_Date__c)  from ObjX__c where id in :setbpid ];
        system.debug('**aggres'+groupedResults );
        Integer minyear = minbp.EPCP_Start_Date__c.year();

        for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
            system.debug('****&&&&^^^');
            System.debug('Min Date' + ar.get('expr0'));
            System.debug('Max Date + ar.get('expr1'));
            Date d = ar.get('expr0');
            Integer maxyear = d.year();
            system.debug('****intmax'+maxyear);
        }
```

Comment: I would expect that you would need to add a cast Date d = (Date) ar.get('expr0'); for this to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Try to cast it to Date after you are fetching the result, such as:

```
 Date d = (Date)ar.get('expr0');
 Integer maxyear = d.year();
 system.debug('****intmax'+maxyear);
```